# Removing space from Java string doesn't work

Tags: java

String input = "c_Name == V-GE-DO50 OR c_Name == V-GE-DO-C";

I have tried

```
input.replaceAll(" ", "");
input.trim();
```

Both did not remove white space from the string

Want the string to look like
    c_Name==V-GE-DO50ORc_Name==V-GE-DO-C

Thanks

Comment: Strings in Java are immutable. You have to assign like this: `String result = input.replaceAll(" ", "");`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note that the `String` methods return a *new* `String` with the transformation applied. `Strings` are immutable - i.e. they can't be changed. So it's a common mistake to do:

```
input.trim();
```

and you should instead assign a variable:

```
String output = input.trim();
```

Comment: Thanks. That helped. Seeing the answers below wonder why it works for some.

Answer (score 5):

Following works fine for me:

```
   String input = "c_Name == V-GE-DO50 OR c_Name == V-GE-DO-C";
   input = input.replaceAll(" ", "");
   System.out.println(input);
```

Output

```
c_Name==V-GE-DO50ORc_Name==V-GE-DO-C
```

Strings are immutable, I strongly suspect you are not assigning the string again after `replaceAll` (or) `trim()`;

One more thing, `trim` doesn't remove spaces in middle, it just removes spaces at end.

Answer (score 0):

input.replaceAll("\s","") should do the trick

http://www.roseindia.net/java/string-examples/string-replaceall.shtml

Answer (score 0):

```
String input = "c_Name == V-GE-DO50 OR c_Name == V-GE-DO-C";
input = input.replaceAll(" ", "");
System.out.println(input);
```

Result:

> > c_Name==V-GE-DO50ORc_Name==V-GE-DO-C

However, replaceAll takes Regular Expression as input value (for replacement) and this case covers getting rid of spaces in variable.
So, if you want to simply get rid of spaces in your String, use input = input.replace(" ", "") to be more efficient.

Comment: Indeed, that's the output. OP needs to use that String for any reason, and your answer doesn't provide using the result at all.