# Trim a string to remove white spaces

Tags: java

I have a string: `"hello world"`. This looks like it has no white space and so I tried to print it out the character `o` in the `hell` part of the string. I just did

```
string.chartAt(4)
```

but to my surprise, it printed out nothing.

I tried to debug it and realized that this string has over 20 leading white spaces. I could still print it out, now that I know where the leading white spaces end but my question is assuming one does NOT know where the white spaces end and one just want to trim the string so it can start printing from the first non-white space letter. How would one do this in Java? Apparently, using `string.trim()` didn't work.

Comment: I think `trim()` should work (leading + trailing removed). You're saying it didn't?

Comment: There are no functions in `String` that will modify an existing string (`String` objects are immutable).  Did you just say `s.trim();` and think that would trim `s`?  If so, you need to say `s = s.trim();`.

Comment: A `String` is immutable. You have to use the `String` instance returned by the `trim()` method, not the original `String` object.

Comment: "*Apparently, using `string.trim()` didn't work.*" it is hard to believe. Can we see some code which proves this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing space from Java string doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12043513/removing-space-from-java-string-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the Javadoc for `String.trim()`:

> Returns a copy of the string, with leading and trailing whitespace omitted.

The original `String` is not modified (`String`s are immutable in Java). So you need to use the object returned after calling `trim()`.

```
// Assuming you have stored the orginial String in a variable called 'myString'
myString = myString.trim ();
System.out.print (myString.charAt(4));

// or

System.out.print (myString.trim ().charAt(4));
```

Answer (score 3):

Like ajb and Laf said in the comments, remember that Strings are immutable. `trim` returns a new, trimmed, string.

```
class TrimTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String hello = "   \n     Hello World     ";
        String trimmedHello = hw.trim();
        System.out.println("'" + trimmedHello + "'");
    }
}
```

Output:

> 'Hello World'

Answer (score 0):

Method `trim()`should work. Remember you must assign the result:

```
result = yourVariable.trim()
```